# get profile picture url from Windows live

Tags: php, json, api, live

In php I try to get the profile picture like this :

```
$tmp = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token='.$accesstoken),true);

echo $tmp['first_name']; // OK (not an accesstoken problem)
```

but if I do :

```
$picture = file_get_contents('https://apis.live.net/v5.0/'.$tmp['id'].'/picture?type=medium&access_token='.$accesstoken);
```

here I get nothing, nothing is returned, strange.

here is the link of the live api : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#user

they said :

> Note  To redirect a GET call to the URL of a user's picture, you can call /me/picture or /USER_ID/picture.

I also tried with https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/picture => but doesn't work too

I don't understand at all, any idea?

Here is the API scope:

scope=wl.emails+wl.basic

---

I've replace file_get_contents with curl :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $t);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
if(preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r))
$picture = trim($r[1]);
```

and now I get this picture url :

https://cid-fbf213653beb66a0.users.storage.live.com/users/0xfbf213653beb66a0/myprofile/expressionprofile/profilephoto**:UserTileMedium**

and now :

- if I open this url in a browser : KO (white page)
- if I remove the bold part above, the browser download the picture (and I can read it if I add .png).

is there a way I get the picture without having to download it?